# Why does bismuth-212 decay to thallium-208?

Tags: radioactivity, nuclear-chemistry

Why does $\ce{_{83}^{212}Bi}$ decay to $\ce{_{81}^{208}Tl}?$

I know that in general the $n/p$ ratio must be less than 1.5 for the nucleus to be stable, but in this case the ratio goes from 1.55 to 1.56, which is more unstable.

Comment: So what? There is no strict dependence between the n/p ratio and stability. Then again, decay into a less stable nucleus is hardly a rare thing. $\rm^{238}U$ does just that.

Comment: oh,OK. Thanks! I was told if the n/p ration becomes more than 1.5, it's automatically unstable

Comment: You mean Thallium, right? Not tellurium.  Note that 208Tl rapidly decays to 208Pb since it is not stable either. There are only so many ways to decay, and 212Bi can't get to 208Pb directly.

Comment: @JonCuster,yes. My bad

Comment: You should seriously refresh your knowledge of periodic table (Te is far away from Bi ) and element symbols (Ti is titanium, even more far away.). Thallium has the symbol Tl. //All heavy and neutron rich isotopes , that undergo alpha decay, lead to even more neutron rich isotopes, which often subsequently undergo beta decay.

Comment: Why is this question about Bi-212? Practically anything that alpha-decays increases its $n/p$ ratio as it does so, and in many cases such as U-238 that ration also starts >1.5.

Comment: That's the specific example I was taught in class

Comment: It has the direct everyday life analogy. Imagine a wrongly built, multistand, vertical holder for flower pots. Upper holders have more potential energy, but lower stand may ( or not ) be less stable, with higher risk of the pot falling down.  Similarly, the isotope, being formed by alpha particle expulsion with energy release, can be less stable than the original one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, there are only a few ways that a nucleus can decay. The primary ones are fission, alpha decay, and beta (plus or minus) and electron capture (I will ignore some of the more exotic paths). This limits the options that an unstable nucleus has to become more stable.

Fission results in two smaller nuclei, with some prompt neutrons and some delayed 'evaporation' neutrons, leaving two lighter nuclei with smaller $n/p$ ratios (mostly). This does not imply that all fission products are stable themselves mind you.

An alpha decay reduces the number of protons and the number of neutrons by two each, so mathematically $n/p$ must increase. Even so the ($\alpha$ + daughter nucleus) can be a lower energy state, partly because the $\alpha$ is so strongly bound.

The $\beta+$, $\beta-$ and EC (electron capture) processes act to turn a single proton into a neutron or vice versa, whichever results in a more stable nucleus.

Looking at $^{212}$Bi (say at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_bismuth)) one sees that it decays through either $\alpha$ (~36% of the time) to $^{208}$Tl or $\beta-$ (~64% of the time) to $^{212}$Po (interstingly, the $^{212m1}$Bi excited state flips those percentages). Neither daughter nucleus is stable, each undergoing the other decay to land at the stable $^{208}$Pb nucleus. Note that the "rule" that nuclei can be stable only with $n/p<1.5$ fails, as this ratio is $\approx1.54$ in the stable $^{208}$Pb product.

Broadly, looking at the various U or Th decay chains will show a variety of branching paths through different daughter nuclei until finally landing on a stable nucleus.

For more info on decays, consider one or both of:

[The AME 2020 atomic mass evaluation](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1674-1137/abddaf) - this is the tables with masses, binding energies, etc.

[Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data Files](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/) - decays, Q values, branching ratios, etc.